# Python Sqlite inserting strings of numbers one at a time

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

So I have made a python script, which collects the creation-, and expirationdates of domainnames from a list of whois -results.

Now I would like to insert these dates into the table, and the hoped result would be

```
24.1.2005
24.1.2017
22.3.2002
```

But what the script inserts into the database is

```
('2')
('4')
('.')
('1')
```

I've tried converting the datatypes in the database to anything I can imagine, and that didn't do the trick.

```
def date():

o = open('outputfile.rtf')

for line in o:

    line = line.replace('\n', '') //Just removing some breaks




    if 'created' in line:

        line = line.replace('created:  ', '')

        creationdate = str(line)

        print (creationdate)
        c.executemany("INSERT INTO pvm (creationdate) VALUES (?)", creationdate)


    conn.commit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit:
Can you try to reformat creationdate to be:

```
creationdate = ['24.1.2005', '22.3.2002', '20.3.2006', '11.12.2013', '22.2.2005', '19.7.2005']
```

Note: In addition to the above - matsutus updated his code to the following line:

```
c.execute("INSERT INTO pvm (creationdate) VALUES (?)", (line,))
```

And the combination of both lines solved the problem.

---

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-executemany.html

***EDIT BY THE ASKER ***

Turning the data into an array, and then making sure the insert execute is

```
c.execute("INSERT INTO pvm (luomispvm) VALUES (?)", (line,))
```

instead of

```
c.execute("INSERT INTO pvm (luomispvm) VALUES (?)", line)
```

Fixed it!

Comment: I changed it to this

    c.execute("INSERT INTO date (creationdate) VALUES (?)", creationdate)

and now all it gives me is 

    sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The    current statement uses 1, and there are 9 supplied.

Comment: what is the result of the following line: "print (creationdate)"?

Comment: It's 24.1.2005
22.3.2002
20.3.2006
11.12.2013
22.2.2005
19.7.2005

Which is the wanted output

Comment: thanks for the info, I've suggested two changes: 1) executemany with %s instead of ?. 2) changing the format of the data of creationdate. - can you try both changes (first - only one change, and then both changes at once)

Comment: Changing the datatype didn't solve it. I also tried the % instead of ?, but it just gave me syntax error. I'll try the array solution. Thanks so far though

Comment: Okay so now I got so far, that I've created an array, where it input all the dates, but still it gives me the "current statement uses 1, and there are 9 supplied" -error. I also tried changing to '%s' but it didn't seem to do anything else than provide syntax errors :l

Comment: did you try the array together with your original executemany command?

Comment: Yes I did. It runs nicely, but when you look at the database, it's 1 number at a time again

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112682/discussion-between-yaron-and-matsutus).